# PHPMailer returning two emails on UPDATE, before and after UPDATE

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've searched the suggestions here and at other sites but can't seem to find an answer for this issue.

I am using PHPMailer to email me a message showing the results of a field value change when a database  UPDATE process has been run. Everything works fine, except I receive two emails, one with the values before the change and one with the new values after the change.

I only want the second email and am wondering how to eliminate the first email being sent.

I've tried using the debugging process but have not been able to successfully eliminate the first email being sent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
   <?php
    require 'database.php';
 
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }
     
    if ( null==$id ) {
        header("Location: homepage.php");
    }
     
    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        $bikeError = null;
        $rideError = null;
        $milesError = null;
        
        $bike = $_POST['bike'];
        $ride = $_POST['ride'];
        $miles = $_POST['miles'];
                
        $valid = true;
        if (empty($bike)) {
            $bikeError = 'Please enter Bike';
            $valid = false;
        }
        
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE rides  set bike = ?, ride = ?, miles = ? WHERE id = ?";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($bike,$ride,$miles $id));
        }
    } else {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM rides where id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $bike = $data['bike'];
        $ride = $data['ride'];
        $miles = $data['miles'];
   }

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/home/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require '/home/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '/home/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                               
    $mail->isSMTP();                                    
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';                  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
    $mail->Username = 'user';            
    $mail->Password = 'paswword';                   
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
    $mail->Port = 587;                                 
    $mail->setFrom('admin@somewhere.net', 'reply');        
    $mail->addAddress('reply@somewhere.net', 'reply'); 

    $mail->isHTML(true);      
    $mail->Subject = 'Ride Edit';
    $mail->Body    =  "Bike: $bike<br>
    Ride: $ride<br>
    Miles: $miles<br>
    ";
    $mail->send();
    echo '';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '';
    echo '' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps the code shown is being *invoked* twice?  What "debugging process" are you using specifically?  What invokes this code?

Comment: It's common for browser plugins to cause repeat posts, but your primary issue is that this script *always* send a message regardless of whether you're doing an update or not. If you want it to only to send when it's doing an update, put it inside the `if ($valid) {` section that does the update.

Comment: Hi Synchro, I thought that might have been an issue and have moved the mailer around in the code but not into an if statement. Sort of new to PDO and every time I moved it somewhere in that section, I get a 'Page Not Working' error when I try to edit the record. Could you show me where you think it show go in the code? Thanks

Comment: Hi David, Yes I think the code is being invoked twice; as soon as the record is accessed from the database, and when it is submitted as an UPDATE when the Submit button is pushed.

Comment: @Rick: Well, if you're invoking this code twice then that would certainly explain why the mail is being sent twice.  It sounds like the problem may be elsewhere.  You'll need to start debugging why you're invoking this twice, which can't be determined from looking only at this.